# OrderBy not working in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am fetching data from firebase and writing it in spreadsheet. I am using google script to do that and there is one library to connect to firebase. Now I want to fetch all the records which are not in my sheet. I have created index on "timestamp". I have timestamp of last row now I want all the records from firebase which have timestamp greater than my timestamp. I am using order by but its not working.

```
var database = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(url, secretKey);
var queryParameters = {orderBy:"timestamp", startAt: {value : 1468078072061}};
var data = database.getData('user', queryParameters);
```

I have created index in this way.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "user": {
      ".indexOn": ["timestamp"]
    }
  }
}
```

But data is coming empty. I tried to give queryParameters differently but its not working.

Comment: Have you tried startAt: 1468078072061 (without value: ...) ?

Comment: Do you get any users when you try var data = database.getData('user') ?

Comment: @Peter yes when I use  var data = database.getData('user')  it is working. And when I use it like startAt: 1468078072061 (without value) it is giving me server error "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 186, file "Code", project "FirebaseApp")".

Comment: Do you have any user with a timestamp before and another after 1468078072061 ? If the original query wasn't wrong then maybe there isn't a user matching your criteria?

Comment: @Peter Yes there are users after 1468078072061